# Validation Error Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-models

Hey so I set up a input form for users to share projects they are working on on a website I have been developing in Django 1.5, I created model, view and Form Model, to allow users who are logged in to add links to projects they are working on.

The Model works and when I enter a text through the admin panel it creates a new object, the views all seem to work, the form loads, and seems to take input however, the Project Name field keeps throwing me a invalid input error when I attempt to fill out the form, not sure why because I am inputing a string, and the field is designated as a CharField in both the Model, and Form Model.

Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
project_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
website = models.URLField(blank=True)
github = models.URLField(blank=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):

    return self.nam
```

View for adding a project:

```
@login_required
def add_project(request):
context = RequestContext(request)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        project.creator = request.user
        project.save()


        return index(request)

    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = ProjectForm()

return render_to_response('rango/add_project.html', {'form' : form}, context)
```

The Form Model:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
project_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="What is the name of your project?")
website = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter the project website:")
github = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter the project github:")
description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, help_text="Description:")
likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

class Meta:

    model = Project 

    exclude = ('creator')

def  clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    website = cleaned_data.get('website')

    #If Url is not empty and dont start with 'http://' prepend 'http://'

    if website and not website.startswith('http://'):
        website = 'http://' + website
        cleaned_data['website'] = website

    return cleaned_data

def  clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    github = cleaned_data.get('github')

    #If Url is not empty and dont start with 'http://' prepend 'http://'

    if github and not github.startswith('http://'):
        github = 'http://' + github
        cleaned_data['github'] = github

    return cleaned_data
```

and lastly the html template:

```
{% extends 'rango/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Add Project {% endblock %}
{% block body_block %}
<H1>Add a new Project</H1>
<form id="project_form" method="post" action="/rango/add_project/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden  in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{hidden}}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{field.errors}}
        {{field.help_text}}
        {{field}}
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Project" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The Page loads fine but when I attempt to submit i get this for project name:

Enter a valid value.

the value I entered was test  for project name.

Comment: Not the problem, but you can't have two `clean` methods - the second will simply overwrite the first when the class is defined. You probably want to define `clean_website` and `clean_github` methods anyway.

Comment: Could You take care of your indentation?

Answer (score 0):

In the `view` function, I do not understand from where `project` comes from.

I would expect instead:

```
project = form.save(commit=False)
project.creator = request.user
project.save()
```